# Selenium code Unable to Run on LambdaTest platform

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, testng, selenium-grid

Selenium code unable to run on LambdaTest platform

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
```

I tried multiple time but same error showing on console.

Multiple browser need to run with different platform and different version.

This is my Java package

```
package lambdatest;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.net.URL;

public class Lambdatest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"browserName", "browserVersion", "platform"})
    public void setUp(String browserName, String browserVersion, String platform) throws Exception {
        
        
        MutableCapabilities capabilities = new MutableCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browserName);
        capabilities.setCapability("browserVersion", browserVersion);
        capabilities.setCapability("platform", platform);
        capabilities.setCapability("name", "LambdaTest Assignment");

        String username = "**************";
        String accessKey = "*************************************";

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testScenario1() {
        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground/");

        // Perform explicit wait

        String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(pageTitle, "LambdaTest"); // Expecting failure
    }
}


[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
Jul 06, 2023 7:34:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer createTracer
INFO: Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Jul 06, 2023 7:34:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver checkNonW3CCapabilities
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [name, platform]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jul 06, 2023 7:34:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver checkNonW3CCapabilities
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [name, platform]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jul 06, 2023 7:34:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver checkNonW3CCapabilities
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [name, platform]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jul 06, 2023 7:34:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver checkNonW3CCapabilities
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [name, platform]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/

===============================================
TestNGAssignmentSuite
Total tests run: 12, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 12
Configuration Failures: 4, Skips: 4
===============================================
```

Comment: Please add the error you received to your post (because this will help to resolve the issue faster)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.